# Describing monitors and semaphores in terms of the three properties of critical section problem solutions

Tags: parallel-computing, concurrency, synchronization

Solutions to the critical section problem exhibit three properties: mutual exclusion, progress, and bounded waiting. When do we say, or do we at least say, that operating system-implemented semaphores and monitors possess all these three properties?

An example would be bounded waiting on semaphores. In bounded semaphores there's a limit on the queue. When the queue is full, is it still safe to say that there is bounded waiting?

Comment: Only one question at a time, please!  Your first question is, I think, answered at this link: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30247/7459.  Your last question, "is it true that monitors are usable for lightweight processes only?" The answer is "no".  The middle question about bounded waiting could be interesting, but needs to be re-written, I think.

Comment: @WanderingLogic Thanks, I modified the question to make it clearer.